# pdus for continuing certification as pmi 's pmp

Tags: acceptance-criteria

I have to collect pdus for my re certification as PMP before July 2017. 
Can I just do self study and online podcasts, webinars to account for 60 PDU
in category A, B And C - Education PDUs .

Do i have to get PDUs  in categoty D E F - Contribution PDUs seperately  ?

Comment: I would suggest that you contact PMI. We have opinions, PMI has answers.

Comment: You should probably read through the Continuing Certification Requirements from PMI (http://www.pmi.org/~/media/PDF/Certifications/handbooks/ccr-certification-requirements-handbook.ashx). They cover their new CCR rules pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe PMI did away with these categories in December. They now require a certain *area* of study instead of a certain *type* of study. I highly recommend reading through this [Infographic Highlighting Changes in PMI PMP® Requirements](http://edward-designer.com/web/new-pmp-pdu-requirements/). You should also go straight to PMI and read their requirements.

Short answer, you don't have to get PDUs in D, E or F category ***but*** you do have to make sure your education is in the right areas of study, which is very different than it was before.